Mounting Bathroom Fan
We are refinishing our basement and added a bathroom. Having hard time mounting the bathroom fan in the space provided. I can’t really mount into the ceiling due to a header.  Any thoughts or suggestions for a top or side mounted bathroom fan?

It appears the picture shows a line of glass blocks covered by something outside, and one space in the run of the glass blocks had a small vent which has been modified to contain an outside dryer vent cover. Does this describe your situation? If so, does the cover outside the glass bocks also cover the dryer vent cover?

What is "the space provided", that missing glass block? If so, why can you not remove another block and frame up a proper space for a ventilator? More info is needed to make this an answerable question; please add details.

It appears the picture shows a line of glass blocks covered by something outside, and one space in the run of the glass blocks had a small vent which has been modified to contain an outside dryer vent flap.
If this accurately describes the situation, and the cover outside the glass blocks does not cover the dryer vent flap, then this setup should be compatible with a wall-mount bathroom fan.
Find a fan compatible with wall mounting, where the exhaust duct will run out horizontally after the fan is mounted on the wall. Place suitable structure over the top of the window at the location of the dryer vent. Mount the fan so the exhaust duct is in line with the dryer vent. You may need to provide a small piece of duct to bridge between the fan and the dryer vent. Have the center line of the fan exhaust duct just a hint higher than the dryer vent center line, to put a slight downward slope on the bridging duct from the fan to the vent, so any possible water incursion in the vent will drain away from the fan.
If the glass blocks are to remain covered by the outside piece, you might put insulation and vapor barriers, etc, in the window area and finish off the wall to cover the blocks. Ask another question for how to finish the wall. If the outside cover can be removed and blocks will remain available for daylight, you can finish off the sides of the fan structure to close off view of the bridging duct and dryer vent.
